# Does this limit exist and if it does what is it?

Tags: limits, convergence-divergence

I was playing around with a few values of $k$ between $0$ and $1$ on Wolfram alpha and found that for all of them

$$\sum_{n= 1}^\infty \frac{\sin(n)}{n^k}$$

converges and I was wondering about the limit as k goes to 0 from the right.

Answer (score 2):

We have
$$\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sin(n)}{n^k}
&= Im\left[ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{e^{in}}{n^k} \right] \\
&= Im\left[ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\left(e^i \right)^n}{n^k} \right] \\
&= Im \left[ \text{Li}_k(e^i) \right]
\end{align}$$
where $\text{Li}$ is the [polylogarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm).

From there, you can look up some results about polylogarithms. Wikipedia says $\text{Li}_0(z) = \frac{z}{1-z}$, so assuming polylogarithm is a continuous function of the index, your answer is
$$\begin{align}
Im\left[ \frac{e^i}{1-e^i} \right]
&= \cdots = \frac 1 2 \cot\left(\frac 1 2\right).
\end{align}$$

Mathematica confirms this result using the following command: `FullSimplify[Limit[Sum[Sin[n]/n^k, {n, 1, Infinity}], k -> 0, Direction -> "FromAbove"]]`

Note this answer is not 100% complete because I have not cited a proof that $\text{Li}_s(z)$ is a continuous function of $s$.

Answer (score 0):

Using the same approach as @David Clyde, $\forall~k>0$
$$\sum_{n= 1}^\infty \frac{\sin(n)}{n^k}=\frac{i}{2}
   \left(\text{Li}_k\left(e^{-i}\right)-\text{Li}_k\left(e^i\right)
   \right)$$ Expanded as series around $k=0^+$
$$\sum_{n= 1}^\infty \frac{\sin(n)}{n^k}=\frac{1}{2} \cot \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)+\frac i 2\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac 1 {n!}\left(\text{Li}^{(n,0)}_0\left(e^{-i}\right)-\text{Li}^{(n,0)}_0\left(e^i\right)\right)\,k^n$$ Making the coefficients rational
$$\sum_{n= 1}^\infty \frac{\sin(n)}{n^k}=\frac{1}{2} \cot \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)+\frac{611}{1487}k-\frac{391}{1061}k^2+\frac{268}{2023}k^3+O(k^4)$$ which is veru decent up to $k=\frac 12$.

To give an idea
$$\int_0^{\frac 12} \Bigg[\text{approximation}- \sum_{n= 1}^\infty \frac{\sin(n)}{n^k}\Bigg]^2\,dk=7.06\times 10^{-8}$$